# Synchronize inno setup run scripts

Tags: inno-setup

I'm trying to run multiple Instructions. I want to synchronize instructions line by line
i.e: `b.exe` cannot be execute until `a.exe` is finished.

```
[Run]
Filename: "a.exe"; 
Filename: "b.exe";
Filename: "c.bat";
Filename: "d.exe"; 
Filename: "e.bat";
```

Comment: Depends on what those entries do. A process can start another process and terminate itself. Then you might get *out of sync*. But anyway, for this task is used the `waituntilterminated` flag which you don't need to specify (it is used by default), hence your example should do what you want.

Comment: You're welcome! But I didn't do anything. As I mentioned, that flag is used by default (you don't need to explicitly include it), so your script should already behave as you want.

Comment: because of this I've found one  more flag "nowait" so i can also execute instructions simultaneously.

Comment: I'm running following scripts:Filename: "{app}\jdk-7u75-windows-x64.exe"; 
Filename: "msiexec.exe"; Parameters: "/i ""{app}\mysql.msi""";
Filename: "{app}\loadDb.bat"; but loadDb.bat is running simultaneously with my sql setup any idea?